# Do-While loop in Python, with limit on the amount of 'do's

Tags: python, error-handling

I'm in a location with poor Internet access. In order to ensure that a call to an external service succeeds, I am wrapping the call in a pseudo-`do-while` in Python. Additionally, I am limiting the call to running a maximum of three times:

```
def post_safe(url, params):

    done = 0
    max_tries = 3
    messages = []

    while done<max_tries:
        try:
            response = requests.post(url, data=params)
        except Exception as e:
            messages.append(e)
            time.sleep(1)
        else:
            done = max_tries+1
        done += 1

    if done==max_tries:
        output = "%s\n" % (datetime.now().strftime('%Y-%m-%d %H:%M'),)
        output+= "requests() failed 3 times:\n"
        for m in messages:
            output+= m+"\n"
        print(output)

        return False

    return True
```

I personally am not satisfied with the 'Pythoness' of this code. It looks inelegant, and I would have preferred to use the type `bool` for `done` but that would require a second variable to count the iterations.

**Is there a cleaner way to achieve a `do-while` in Python while limiting the amount of iterations?**

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The `else` branch in your `try` is hackish (skipping over the `max_tries`) so I added `success` variable.
(Although you asked not to avoid it in the question, I think it's the better way, and I'll explain why.)

It also nicely allowed me to

- replace `if done==max_tries` with `if not success`;
- remove `else` branch altogether;
- return `success` instead of having two `return` statements.

I think it reads more easily now.

```
def post_safe(url, params):
    messages = []

    success = False
    max_retries = 3
    retries = 0

    while retries < max_retries and not success:
        try:
            response = requests.post(url, data=params)
            success = True
        except Exception as e:
            messages.append(e)
            time.sleep(1)

        retries += 1

    if not success:
        output = "%s\n" % (datetime.now().strftime('%Y-%m-%d %H:%M'),)
        output+= "requests() failed 3 times:\n"
        for m in messages:
            output+= m+"\n"
        print(output)

    return success
```

You **can** also get rid of `success` by returning `True` early in `try`:

```
def post_safe(url, params):
    messages = []

    retries = 0
    max_retries = 3

    while retries < max_retries:
        try:
            response = requests.post(url, data=params)
            return True
        except Exception as e:
            messages.append(e)
            time.sleep(1)

        retries += 1

    output = "%s\n" % (datetime.now().strftime('%Y-%m-%d %H:%M'),)
    output+= "requests() failed 3 times:\n"
    for m in messages:
        output+= m+"\n"
    print(output)

    return False
```

I **don't** like this approach. It wins us a variable and two lines but obfuscates the flow:

- In which case will the last block run? When we had an `if not success` condition, it was obvious, but now from a quick glance it *looks* like this block executes every time;
- What are function's `return` points? The first example had just one, and it was obvious what the return value represented.

Let me quote [PEP 20](http://www.python.org/dev/peps/pep-0020/):

- Sparse is better than dense.
- Readability counts.

Finally, `success` may be an “extra” variable from computer's point of view, but for a human, it's *the* expression that determines if the last block of code runs. It's good to *give it a name*.

Comment: Thanks, Dan. Though just a tad more readable, I don't like the use of the extra variable (I mention that in the OP). I do think that the extra readability is due to the better-named variable (`done` was a terrible name). I'm hoping that a more 'Pythonic' answer comes along. I would almost expect this to be a common design pattern.

Comment: @dotancohen I added a second example that doesn't need `success`, but personally I find it less obvious.

Comment: There were some terrific answers here. I choose this answer based on the readability. It _feels_ wasteful, but it is very readable and maintainable. Thank you!

Answer (score 9):

Python has a language feature just for that: [`else` clauses on loops](http://docs.python.org/2/tutorial/controlflow.html#break-and-continue-statements-and-else-clauses-on-loops).

> Loop statements may have an `else` clause; it is executed when the loop terminates through exhaustion of the list (with `for`) or when the condition becomes false (with `while`), but not when the loop is terminated by a `break` statement.

```
def post_safe(url, params):
    max_tries = 3
    messages = []

    for _ in range(max_tries):
        try:
            response = requests.post(url, data=params)
            return True
        except Exception as e:
            messages.append(e)
            time.sleep(1)

    else:
        print(datetime.now().strftime('%Y-%m-%d %H:%M'))
        print("requests() failed %d times:" % (max_tries))
        for m in messages:
            print(m)
        return False
```

I'd also make the following changes:

- The `else` clause on the `try` block is unnecessary; it can be replaced with a `break` within the `try` block just after calling `.post()`.  But in the end, you'll just end up returning `True`, so why not get out of there right away with `return True`?  (For that matter, the `else` block that I just suggested is also unnecessary, as the `else` could be removed and its contents outdented by one level.)
- It seems easier to print each line separately than to build a multi-line string to print all at once.  You might want to consider [`logging`](http://docs.python.org/2/library/logging.html) instead.

Comment: huh ... lsned - learn something new every day.

Comment: Considering the `return True` in the `try` block, the `else` clause on the `for` loop is unnecessary too! But I must say, `for-else` is great and thank you for mentioning it.

Answer (score 3):

One of the beauties of Python is that it can be made to read like English. With a very small amount of messing with your code, you can get to this, which I feel is much more readable:

```
def post_safe(url, params):

    done = False
    tries_left = 3
    messages = []

    while tries_left and not done:
        tries_left -= 1
        try:
            response = requests.post(url, data=params)
            done = True
        except Exception as e:
            messages.append(e)
            time.sleep(1)

    if not done:
        output = "%s\n" % (datetime.now().strftime('%Y-%m-%d %H:%M'),)
        output+= "requests() failed 3 times:\n"
        for m in messages:
            output+= m+"\n"
        print(output)

    return done
```

Comment: Great idea about decrementing the counter.

Comment: That's what optimization freaks teach you to do in C: it seems that comparing to 0 is cheaper in some computer architectures...

Comment: Thank you, I also like the idea of decrementing the counter. I'll deliberate a bit before choosing one of the two excellent answers. Maybe a third will show up in the meantime!

Comment: nit-pick - sometimes I like `val += 1` instead of `val++` because it makes sense in that context, but, because `-` and `=` look more alike, I never recommend `val -= 1`. just use `val--`

Comment: @rolfl I see your point, but `val--` is not valid Python syntax...

Comment: @Jaime - I only open my mouth to swap feet. Appreciate that you didn't add 'idiot' to your comment ;-)

Answer (score 1):

Consider stripping the method down to the essential `requests.post()` call, and using the [`@retry`](https://pypi.python.org/pypi/retrying) decorator instead.

Comment: Thank you, I will try the `retrying` package. Note that I reverted your edit, as this question is about the general case of do-while in Python, not the specific HTTP request issue that is used as an example of why it is necessary.

Comment: But a `do`-`while` differs from a `while` in exactly that aspect:  A thing is done at least once and *maybe* again and again.  There is at least a strong relation to the idea of a retry in that.